# Liferay: Select webcontent programmatically

Tags: java, portlet, liferay-6

I'm trying to create pages with a JOURNAL_CONTENT included programmatically.
I follow [this liferay guide](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Programmatically+Create+a+Layout+and+Place+a+Portlet+on+it?_36_pageResourcePrimKey=4361716) but nothing.
Layouts are created with a journal_content inside, but no article is displayed.
It seems everything correct, i tried two ways to select article:

```
PortletPreferences prefs = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(companyId, ownerId, ownerType, newPage.getPlid(), journalPortletId);
prefs.setValue("articleId", content.getArticleId());
prefs.setValue("groupId", String.valueOf(groupId));
//prefs.setValue("article-id", content.getArticleId());
//prefs.setValue("group-id", String.valueOf(groupId));
```

If I debug *html/portlet/journal_content/view.jsp* the param "articleId" is always null.
Any solution?